# Jaeger query and collector pods do not start

Tags: jaeger

While deploying jaeger 1.28.0 on
Kubernetes version v1.21.2-1555+9e8f924492b7d7-dir
OpenShift version 4.8.0-0.okd-2021-11-14-052418

Facing the below errors query and collector pods do not start.

**QUERY:**
MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "jaeger-oi-service-ca" : configmap references non-existent config key: service-ca.crt
MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "jaeger-oi-ui-oauth-proxy-tls" : secret "jaeger-oi-ui-oauth-proxy-tls" not found

**jaeger-oi-collector**
MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "jaeger-oi-collector-tls-config-volume" : secret "jaeger-oi-collector-headless-tls" not found

My simplest.yaml file is below:-

```
apiVersion: jaegertracing.io/v1
kind: Jaeger
metadata:
  name: jaeger-oi
spec:
  strategy: production
  collector:
    image: jaegertracing/jaeger-collector:1.28.0
    maxReplicas: 1
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "4Gi"
        cpu: "2"
      limits:
        memory: "8Gi"
        cpu: "4"
  query:
    image: jaegertracing/jaeger-query:1.28.0
    replicas: 1
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "4Gi"
        cpu: "2"
      limits:
        memory: "8Gi"
        cpu: "4"    
  agent:
    strategy: sidecar
    image: jaegertracing/jaeger-agent:1.28.0    
  storage:
    type: elasticsearch
    esIndexCleaner:
      enabled: false
    dependencies:
      enabled: false
    options:
      es:
        use-aliases: false
        server-urls: https://*******      
  ui:
      options:
       dependencies:
        menuEnabled: false
        tracking:
          gaID: UA-000000-2
       menu:
        - label: "About Jaeger"
          items:
           - label: "Documentation"
             url: "https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/latest"
       linkPatterns:
         - type: "logs"
           key: "customer_id"
           url: /search?limit=20&lookback=1h&service=frontend&tags=%7B%22customer_id%22%3A%22#{customer_id}%22%7D
           text: "Search for other traces for customer_id=#{customer_id}"
```

Answer (score 0):

With openshift the Jaeger UI is protected with OAuth service and only valid user is able to login.
An extra oauth service was causing all the issues.
As a workaround, I disabled this feature by setting Ingress property to none in my simplest.yaml

```
ingress:
   security: none
```